# How does facebook login button gets user info when "data-use-continue-as" it on?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I mean this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Are there ways to get user profile picture and name as you can get in "Continue as {name}" button? I would like to get such info in my custom login button, is it possible?

I know I can get such info if user is connected to facebook and to my app, but that "Continue as {name}" button shows such info even if user is not related to my app at all. So is there a way to get it? :)

Comment: rule of thumb: no user data at all without authorization

Comment: so facebook is doing some magic with that "Continue as {name}" button?

Comment: nothing magical about that, social plugins are black boxes (iframes) FROM facebook. of course they can access user data.